# Serial Port reading causes application freezing for a while - Do I need threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I got some code in c# for reading results of AT command compatible modem. 
In case I start COM port reading whole apps freezes until data received. I suppose I should use threading but I've no idea how ?

```
        if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            serialPort1.Open();
        serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 5000;
        serialPort1.NewLine = "\r\n";
        serialPort1.WriteLine("AT#MON");
        serialPort1.NewLine = "\r\n";
        while (true) // Loop indefinitely
        {

            serialPort1.NewLine = "\r\n"; // Prompt
            string linee = serialPort1.ReadLine(); // Get string from port

            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(linee, ("^xcqa:")))
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(linee, ("^fkss:")))
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(linee, ("ended"))) // Check string
            {
                break;
            }
            textBox1.AppendText(linee);
        }
```

Comment: Isn't there an event you can use to handle reading data from the serial port?

Comment: This is why SerialPort has the DataReceived event.  It runs on a worker thread, you'll have to use Control.BeginInvoke().

Comment: Thanks for all off You... I'm completely beginner in C# :-) I was not able to find an example code

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to use multithreading. Spawning a new thread will allow other code in your application to carry on simultaneously. For this, your serial port read code would need its own thread. Read up on multithreading doc for C#.

- [Threading Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)
- [Introduction to Multithreading in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/MultithreadingIntro10062005000439AM/MultithreadingIntro.aspx)